# achartengine setLabelsTextSize doesn't apply to annotations of all renderers

Tags: java, android, css, achartengine

I have annotations in my chart and I'm trying to increase their font size. So, I'm using setLabelsTextSize() method of XYMultipleSeriesRenderer (Is there a better way?). But this isn't taking effect on annotations of all renderers. It is taking effect only for the first renderer. Below are some snippets from my code.

```
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer render = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();    
XYSeriesRenderer a = new XYSeriesRenderer();
a.addAnnotation("Sept-03", 2, 1.4);
XYSeriesRenderer a = new XYSeriesRenderer();
b.addAnnotation("Oct-03", 3, 2.4);
render.addSeriesRenderer(a);
render.addSeriesRenderer(b);
render.setLabelsTextSize(20);
```

Here, only "Sept-03" has bigger font size. "Oct-03" still has small font size.

Am I doing something wrong or missing something? Or is this a bug in achartengine library? Has anyone else faced this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to set the annotations text size, you will have to use:

```
renderer.setAnnotationsTextSize(size);
```

Comment: Thanks! FYI for others, renderer here is XYSeriesRenderer.